# javascript: click on table1 column slide to display table2 column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Brief:**
In **Mobile Screen** would like to Click on Column in **Table 1** will **Hide** it and **Slide** to display a Column in **Table 2** and I can Click on back button to return back to Column in **Table 1** using Javascript/jQuery or it can been done with the help of **CSS** too. How i can do that and provide an example will be much of help too ?

Screenshot of current page:

https://ibb.co/51SRgKw

Current page structure:

```html
<div class="panel-body blocking">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 manage-at__scroll" style="padding:0px;">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Class Names</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <a style="font-weight: bold;color:#333" href="#">Actual Class Names List</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 manage-at__scroll" style="padding:0px;">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Student Names</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <a style="font-weight: bold;color:#333" href="#">Actual Student Names List</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 manage-at__scroll" style="padding:0px;">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="student_attendance">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Absent Dates</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gradeX odd">
                        <td align="center">
                            <p class="text-left">
                                <strong>Actual Absent Dates List</strong>
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-left"></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="text-left">
                                <input type="text">
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my idea with jquery i will use [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/) to switch your div, first load set style is `display:none`.

or use [jquery mobile](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages-multi-page/index.html).

```js
$(function(){
  
   let switch_page = function(p_id){
     $('.manage-at__scroll').hide(200)
     $(`#${p_id}`).show(200);
   }
  
  $('a.list-class').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    switch_page('tab2');
  });
  
  $('a.list-st').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    switch_page('tab3');
  });
  
  $('#b1').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    switch_page('tab1');
  });
  
  $('#b2').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    switch_page('tab2');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body class="container">
<div class="panel-body blocking">
    <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-lg-4 manage-at__scroll" style="padding:0px;" id="tab1">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Class Names</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <a class="list-class" style="font-weight: bold;color:#333" href="#">Actual Class Names List</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 manage-at__scroll" style="padding:0px;display:none;" id="tab2">
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" id="b1"> back </a>
            </p>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Student Names</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <a class="list-st" style="font-weight: bold;color:#333" href="#">Actual Student Names List</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 manage-at__scroll" style="padding:0px;display:none;" id="tab3">
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" id="b2"> back </a>
            </p>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="student_attendance">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Absent Dates</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gradeX odd">
                        <td align="center">
                            <p class="text-left">
                                <strong>Actual Absent Dates List</strong>
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-left"></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="text-left">
                                <input type="text">
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks it is work fine but when click on back button on Student Names it does not display Column in table 1 named Class Names Also when go back how i can remove the selection from the current column